# data to show onmouse over

Tags: html, css

I have a scenario, where I have to show the data in tooltip. complete data is not visible in the tooltip,is there a way we can increase tooltip window size?

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the html or maybe a jsfiddle

Comment: are you trying to get the hover effect in [this Glossary?](http://192.254.245.38/~energy/html.diyg.com/Resource-GrantArticles-Glossary.html)

Comment: @ Chris M - Yes , when i mouse over the status "FAIL" it has to show me the tooltip with details (start time, end time and duration in the table ).

Comment: is the table data populated dynamically or is it just static html? can you add your html to your question?

Comment: table data is dynamic getting from database.

Answer (score 1):

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/XVCQ8/1/) for what I think you are looking for.
there is a bit of extra styling in there but it should work for your situation.

html:

```
<a class="tooltip">FAIL
    <span class="custom define"><em>Start Time:</em>Wed, May 07, 2014<br />
        <em>EndTime:</em>blah blah<br />
        <em>Duration:</em>blah blah
    </span>
</a>
```

css:

```
.tooltip {
    cursor: help;
    position: relative;
}
.tooltip span {
    margin-left: -999em;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index:999999998;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    opacity:1.0;
    position: absolute;
    display:inline;
    left: 110%;
    top: 10%;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 450px;
}
.tooltip:hover em {
    font-family: Candara, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.2em 0 0.6em 0;
}
.custom {
    padding: 0.5em 0.8em 0.8em 2em;
}
* html a:hover {
    background: transparent;
}
.define {
    background: #efefef;
    border: 2px solid #009900;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris M. But that is not working. Please see the image i have included above when i kept the code you mentioned.

Comment: post your html or a link to your site or put it in a fiddle

Comment: Actually its interdependent and iam getting dynamic data from database ,based on condition i am building the tooltip in java program,Please see the above question, i have placed the java code.

Comment: some of the screen shot is cut off, is all of the data making it into the tooltip but the problem is the table cells with a border?

Comment: yes Chris,in the page ther are 'n' columns and rows. please see the screenshot above. Problem is as youmentioned with the table cells how can i make work even if table end.

Comment: i don't know java but it looks like an overflow: issue in that screenshot. if you can style the table you are hovering over with css, i would suggest `overflow:visible;`

Comment: ok.I tired overflow:visible; but still its not showing the remaining rows in tooltip, as the table got end even the tooltip not showing the extra data.

Comment: Thanks Chris M for your effort and time.

Comment: wish I could help more.  would you mind marking the answer as useful at least, you don't have to mark it correct.  thanks